# can't open saved plot in R

Tags: r, plot, save

I am not able to open the plot when saved as pdf or other format. Consistently getting the following error. I am working on mac.

```
> plot(1:10)
> pdf('deleteIt.pdf')
> dev.off()
RStudioGD 
        2 


> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] pROC_1.5.4 plyr_1.7.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.15.1
```

I am getting the following error. Itried with png and jpeg too, but no luck..

```
The file “deleteIt.pdf” could not be opened.
It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You did it backwards.  Try this

```
pdf("deleteIt.pdf")
plot(1:10)
dev.off()
```

Start the device.  Write to it.  Turn it off.

---

Alternatively, as pointed out by [@Spacedman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/211116/spacedman) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487328/cant-open-saved-plot-in-r/14487392#comment20194700_14487392), you can create a pdf with whatever is currently plotted by using `dev.copy` like this:

```
plot(1:10)
dev.copy(pdf, "deleteIt.pdf")
dev.off()
```

Comment: Dang -- beat me by 10 seconds!

Comment: my fault. Sorry. I was thinking to write it the way we write other files.

Comment: You can also do: `plot(1:10); dev.copy(pdf); dev.off()` if you want to copy something already on the screen graphics device to a PDF!